# Ionic 3 - Show JSON response from HTTP request in formatted way

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My Ionic 3 app makes HTTP requests to a Rails backend. If the request is successful the app does whatever it has to do and when there is an error the API returns and HTTP error code and a JSON error message.

I want my app to show an alert with the Error message in a nice way for the user and not as JSON.

```
error => {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Algo não deu certo...',
  subTitle: error.text(),
  buttons: ['OK']
});
```

This results in:

[image]

I would like to have it formatted. I know that I can loop through the items and display them but I would like to know if there is a easier way/less code to do it.

Comment: Hi @almo can you provide what you have inside ERROR data?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well you need something like:

```js
const error = {
  "from": ["can't be blank"],
  "to": ["can't be blank"],
  "passenger": ["must exist"],
};

const errorMessage = Object.keys(error).reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc} ${cur} ${error[cur]}`, '').slice(1);

console.log(errorMessage);
```

This is basic example with `Array#Reduce`.

Here you are another example with formatted text:

```js
const error = {
  "from": ["can't be blank"],
  "to": ["can't be blank"],
  "passenger": ["must exist"],
};

const errorMessage = Object.keys(error).reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc} ${cur.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${cur.slice(1)}: ${error[cur]}!`, "").slice(1);

console.log(errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

As error will be executed only when it returns error you can give a error message in text form like this:

```
error => {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'Algo não deu certo...',
subTitle: 'Your error Message',
buttons: ['OK']
});
```